# Backward change transport from QAS to DEV?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I developed many programs on DEV environment then I transported them to QAS.
Then, a problem occurred and the system administrator restored an old version of DEV without taking a backup of the recent version, so I lost many programs that I developed in DEV.

I am wondering if there is a way to transport them from QAS to DEV?

Comment: Theoretically it is possible: a transport request has to be created in QAS, all objects have to be added manually to the transport request, the request has to be released and imported into DEV. You need all required authorizations and most likely you need the support of Basis for the last step (import back into DEV)

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai Can you tell me please how to achieve the step to import back the TR into DEV?

Comment: And the way to know the corresponding TR for each Program, smartforms ... ?

Comment: @A.lkram Basis guys can helpm you by putting the transport back to DEV (most likely the files have to be copied manually between servers)

Comment: Do the transport requests for these programs still exist?

Comment: `And the way to know the corresponding TR for each Program, smartforms ... ?` usually via Version menu, but its location can vary per object, so SE03 is your friend

Comment: As József said, all the transport requests are stored separately, so they should not be lost. The admin should be able to restore all the transport requests released after the DEV backup.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to avoid using the transport system to restore those objects, then the 3rd party program [ZABAPGIT](https://docs.abapgit.org/) might help you. It allows you to export all development objects from a packet or a transport request into a zip file and then import that zip file in a different system.

This program does not care about the usual transport paths. When you import objects into a system using this program, then they will be treated as if they were created in that system.

Comment: actually it is no longer "third-party" and is recommended by SAP as an official way to migrate code on-prem2cloud and vice versa, as well for other scenarios https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/abap-environment-abapgit.html

Answer (score 0):

Se10 - Create a Transport of Copies.
Manually add the programs

```
r3tr prog xxxxxx
```

or for classes

```
r3tr clas xxxxxx
```

release the transport with virtual/dummy target (not prod).

In STMS in dev
add the transports to the buffer.
Import them.   You will most likely need the overwrite original option.

Be sure you have the write objects ;)

OPTION 2:   if it is only source code. And you have Eclipse as IDE.
Connect both QAS and DEV in Eclipse.
Open the object in DEV.

Use the compare with QAS option.
right click in source code "Compare"
Copy the deltas back to dev.

[image]